# PHP - is there a way in php to design our own command?

Tags: php, terminal

In PHP is there a way to design our own command which can be run in ubuntu Terminal as in the below example? The command call would look like that:

```
Command: `php talent-test:get-reports`
```

Output should look like the output below in the Terminal:

```
Report Status:
Total Proceed: 100 Records.
Total Success: 90 Records.
Total Failed : 10 Records.
```

And the above command will get reports from my Database and whatever code I write in my PHP file. Also, can that above command be linked to my reports.php file?

Comment: have you heard of **[command line args](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)**?

Comment: Can you please write a sample code for me what i'm looking for?

Comment: no. you have to show at least a **tiny** bit of effort by yourself. read the manual page i've linked to, if you can't figure *anything* out after reading the *already existing examples*, you might want to consider some choices.

Answer (score 1):

Create a *shell script* with the PHP command saved inside. For example:

Save a file like *run-reports.sh* in the same directory as your PHP script (or if you save it in a different directory, then the path to the PHP script will need to be absolute or relative to the directory containing the shell script file). Presuming your PHP script is named *talent-test.php*, then add this line to the that shell script file:

```
php talent-test.php get-reports
```

Then in your PHP script, [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) will contain the arguments.

```
<?php
echo print_r($argv);

 // array( 0 => "talent-test.php", 1 => "get-reports")
if (isset($argv) && isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] == "get-reports") {
    //logic to run reports 
}
```

Then in the terminal, run that shell script, like so:

```
$./run-reports.sh
```

Or

```
$sh run-reports.sh
```

For more information about creating a shell script, see pages like [this one](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec01.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can run PHP script as if it is a shell script already using the terminal. You can also customize your own commands;
http://www.tecmint.com/run-php-codes-from-linux-commandline/

Comment: that is Interactive shell we can write code but how to make our own cmd and that cmd will execute our php file ?